# Origins of the standard Ketubah text we use today

Tags: ketubah, maseches-kesubos, even-haezer

[Maseches Ketubot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketubot_(tractate)) deals all about the laws related to the Ketubah, and these laws (ex: the amount of money, obligations) are codified in the  **Shulchan Aruch** Even Haezer *simanim* 66-118.

However, while all the halachot are dealt with here I didn't see a "sample" writeup of what the Ketubah text should look like.

Nowadays-- although there may be minor differences-- pretty much all Orthodox ketubot follow the same standard structure and language (see [RCA](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubah_Text.1?lang=bi), and [Chabad](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/532557/jewish/Ketubah.htm) etc).

**What's the earliest source of this structured Ketubah text that we** (almost universally) **still follow to this day?**

Comment: From WIKI: הכתובה הקדומה ביותר הקיימת היא הכתובה ממרשה הכתובה על גבי חרס... כתובה זו מתוארכת לשנת 176 לפנה"ס - עוד לפני שמעון בן שטח, כתובה בארמית ומזכירה את הכתובות של ימינו. חוקרים משערים שמדובר בטיוטה של כתובה, ולא בכתובה ממש.[דרוש מקור]

Comment: You only listed Ashkenazi websites/texts.